# API Java Speech, em Português

Tags: java

É possível gerar um sintetizador de voz usando a `API Java Speech`, porém com *sotaque* ***Aportuguesado***?
Não entendo muito de `Java`, se for possível detalhar a resposta, agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vi, da para chegar a esse resultado com certo grau de esforço.
Esse [Link](http://www.guj.com.br/t/java-speech-api-portugues/82645) indica os caminhos a seguir:
`IBM Via Voice`;
Outro sintetizador - `mbrola`